# What gives!? Chrome on Mac won't clear autofill data

Tags: macos, google-chrome, autofill

I've been going crazy because in Chrome on my MacBook Air there was some autofill data from my previous job that would not go away.  This was driving me nuts because I cleared all the autofill data about 100 times, cleared the cache, did all sorts of things and the data was still there.  I also did tons of searching, but couldn't find anybody else with this problem.  Frustration!

Answer (score 0):

Well, today I figured it out, and I'm posting this to help that next frustrated soul avoid the problem.  It turns out it's simple.

The whole problem originates from this box checked in the Chrome Autofill settings:

[image]

The problem is that I had some data in my Address Book (i.e. Contacts app) that contained my the address, email, etc. from my previous job.  By simply removing that data solved the problem.

I hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

Solution:

Go to Chrome, select clear browsing data,

Make sure to select ''From the Beginning of Time'' on the **Obliterate the following items from** option:

tick all the boxes, and try it.

Done.